# What time system is this?

Tags: time

Im trying to understand some program that handles time in a certain system I am still to know of. Hopefully you can tell me what system is, if any.

One of the value in numbers is 170000000 and it represents the 26th of April 2037. Another example is 164632577 which represents the 20th of December 2022.

I tested both with an EPOCH converter but I get completely different dates so its not EPOCH for sure. Have any clue?

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to tag language and perhaps also list what functions you are using to get those values.

Comment: Its from a game, and I really dont have a clue about what language is this written on.

Comment: You don't know what language it is written in, but you are trying to understand it? I would think identifying what language the program is in would be a first step. Then reference material for that language might help you.

Comment: I know what you mean but the thing is that I am just trying to figure out whats the pattern of the time and nothing else. I cant get too deep into it because I am no expert.

Answer (score 2):

We assume that the fomula for converting from a date to those strange time units is of the following form:

```
f(x) = m*x + b
```

where x is in strange time units and f is in days:

f(2037*365.2425       + 31 + 28 + 31 + 26) = 170000000
f(2022*365.2425 + 365.2425 - (31 + 1 - 20) = 164632577

because we have two data points, we can make two formulas:
I : f1 = m * x1 + b
II: f2 = m * x2 + b

Now we’re looking for: m, b

We solve as follows:

I => III: `b = f1 - m*x1`

III into II: `f2 = m*x2 + f1 - m*x1 => f2 - f1 = m(x2 - x1) => m = (f2 - f1) / (x2 - x1)`

goes down to:

```
m = 1024.04 units/day and (exactly 1024, most likely, because that’s 2^10)
```

with b = f1 - m*x1

```
b = -591973731.84 (??)
```

so you get:

for converting from days since year 1 to those strange time units:

```
f(x) = 1024 * x - 591973731.84
```

where x is in days, so year * 365.2524 + (months-1) * 30 + days

testing it reveals that
`f(Jan 1st 2038 = 2038*365.2425) = 1024*2038*365.2425 - 591973731.84 = 170255224.3`, which is just a bit more than Dec 20th 2037, so it works.

Strangely, the 0 point of those strange time units represents about the year 1582 (solution for x of `f(x) = 0`).

Comment: The Gregorian calendar was introduced in october 1582, it seems reasonable that the number is based on that. Also, using 1024 units per day sounds a lot more appealing to me than my attempts to use 1000. Everyone knows that 1024 is a much more even number!

Comment: Hi,yes, indeed. Before reading your answer I tested different values and i came to the same conclusion. A day is represented by 1024. But seems like there is no indication of a well established system and its rather a thing someone just made up.

Answer (score 2):

170000000 seems very rounded. Do you know exact seconds within the game your numbers represent?

It should be a linear system, and you know that the value of (170000000 - 164632577) = 5367423 equals the difference between your days (2037-04-26 - 2022-12-20) = 5241 days.

This means that one day is (5241 / 5367423) = 0.00097644623873...

Counting back from 164632577 to zero places takes us back (164632577 * 0.00097644623873...) = 160754.86 days, from 2022-12-20 to 1582-11-02.

Same calculations done on 170000000 takes us back (170000000 * 0.00097644623873...) = 165995,86 days, from 2037-04-26 to 1582-11-02. Heuruka!

So, you have a system where `timeFor($value) = [1582-11-02] + [0.00097644623873... * $value days]`.

Issues:

- There are several rounding issues with these numbers. Your dates most probably include seconds, but we've calculating on whole days.
- We're moving back in time, and time travel related issues will appear. These include, but are not limited to, non existing dates according to your calendar.

Things to consider; October 15th of 1582, or 1582-10-15 is the start of the Gregorian calender. This is probably the real start date for your data.

Edit: I previously wrote that the multiplier should probably be 0.001, but as Daniel noted in another answer, it's actually 1/1024 = 0.0009765625.

Comment: I didn't know the start of the gregorian calendar. +1 for that. About the 1000: 1 / 0.00097644623873 = 1024.12, so I think it should be 1024.

Comment: I chose that value because I thought it was easier to start up from a rounded number. I think too that the numbers include seconds or at least hours but i dont see them anywhere so i guess its enough with understanding how to get a certain day without minding the hour.

Comment: 1024 units per day is accurate only down to a bit worse than 1 minute.